# Do ADO (TFS) dashboards support tabs?

Tags: tfs, ado, dashboard

I'm using ADO dashboards.( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/overview?view=azure-devops ). 
I want to have many different charts / query tile views, each serving a distinct purpose but they are all related to a project. Right now I have to create distinct dashboards for each. Is there a way to have tabs within one dashboard so i can still separate the views but not have to go to different dashboards all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this is **not available**, we do not have tabs in the dashboard at the moment.

You may have to go to different dashboards and manually select/switch the view.

You could create a related user voice and vote up in our [feature request page](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) from Developer Community site. Our PM will kindly review your suggestion.

[image]